# How to create a field in django model using values of other fields of same model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-2.1

I wants to create a field name:**total** which have the total price of all the products*quqantity. What I want is how can I do `total = price*quantity` in django model. As you can see there can be more than one products.
I have join the OderItem model with Order through tabularinline.

[image]

```js
class OrderItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    raw_id_fields = ['product']

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','name', 'mobile_no','address','status', 'created']
    list_editable = ['status']
    list_per_page = 15
    list_filter = ['status']
    search_fields = ('id',)
    inlines = [OrderItemInline]


admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

```html
class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60,default=None, blank=True)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=13, default=None) 
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status_choices = (
        ('In Queue', 'In Queue'),
        ('Processing', 'Processing'),
        ('Ready', 'Ready'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
        ('Paid', 'Paid'),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    ) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15,       choices=status_choices, default=status_choices[0][0])


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())



class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(MenuVariant, related_name='order_items', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    # total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,default=0)



    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

Comment: What do you mean you want "to create a field total"? You want to display the total price in the admin? Or you want to have access to the total in your code?

Comment: wants to do both

Comment: But you already have it in your code: `order.get_total_cost()`.

Comment: it only show the total price of one product e.g price * quantity

Comment: huh? it's the sum of the cost for all items, not just one product. Your code is correct.

Comment: @dirkgroten i want to create a field which take  the price of first product and its quantity and then multiply price and quantity and store it in total and then it take the price of second product and save its price in total= total+price and so on

Comment: why store something in the database that can be calculated from the other columns (that's bad practice)? and store it where? you want to add a field `total` to which model?

Comment: @dirkgroten in order model

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total price for an `Order` directly with a database query, so there's no need to save it in the database:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, FloatField
orders = Order.objects.annotate(total=Sum(F('items__quantity')*F('items__price'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

This adds a `total` field to each result of the query. So then:

```
price_of_first_order = orders.first().total
```

And if you want to display the total for an `order` in the admin, subclass the `ModelAdmin` and add `get_total_cost` to the `readonly_fields`, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

> A read-only field can not only display data from a model’s field, it can also display the output of a model’s method or a method of the ModelAdmin class itself. This is very similar to the way ModelAdmin.list_display behaves.

Comment: i add this code in order model or order item model?

Comment: as u said that get_total_cost function is doing what im asking then how can i do total= get_total_cost in model

Comment: hey can u help me out?

Comment: See the answer below of @amazonic if you really want to save it. But as I said, it's bad practice to do that, because it's redundant and will almost certainly at some stage lead to inconsistent data in your database. You need to always keep one source of truth, saving this to the database creates a second source for the same truth.

Comment: im confuse how to use the code that u provided i copy past the code in Order model but it is not working  .im new to django and im doing this first time.

Comment: My answer contains two things: First an explanation why you should not save the total in the model (because it's easy to get the total anywhere you need it in your code by performing the query I showed). Second how to display the total in the admin. Just add `get_total_cost` as readonly field to your ModelAdmin and you'll see the total for each order appear in the Order change view.

Comment: when I run ur code it give this output "
<QuerySet [<Order: Order 3>, <Order: Order 4>, <Order: Order 5>, <Order: Order 6>, <Order: Order 7>, <Order: Order 8>, <Order: Order 9>]>"

Comment: when i add get_total to readonly fields it shows an empty field in admin

Answer (score 1):

While I, like dirkgroten don't quite see the point of saving the value in a model field, you could add a field `total=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)` to your `Order` model and use a `post_save` to update the value.

So, since you already have a `get_total_cost()` we can do something like:

```
def order_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.total_cost = instance.get_total_cost()

pre_save.connect(order_pre_save, sender=Order)
```

EDIT: As dirkgroten points out you'll need the `post_save` on the `OrderItem`:

```
def order_item_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.order.total_cost = instance.order.get_total_cost()
    instance.order.save()

post_save.connect(order_item_pre_save, sender=OrderItem)
```

And you'd also need to update the value on delete:

```
def order_item_pre_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.order.total_cost = instance.order.get_total_cost() - instance.get_cost()
    instance.order.save()

post_delete.connect(order_item_pre_delete, sender=OrderItem)
```

Comment: this would work, but you'd want to connect saving `OrderItem`, not `Order`, to update the field on `Order`. So it would be `instance.order.total_cost = instance.order.get_total_cost(); instance.order.save()`

Comment: the problem is that you should also update it when an OrderItem is deleted. Also these signals are not called in certain circumstances, e.g. when a bulk update or bulk create occurs.

Comment: when i run the order_item_pre_save func it gives error OrderItem is not defined

Comment: Have you defined your new function in your `models.py`? Put your post/pre-saves at the bottom of the `models.py` where your model is.